# NSpredicate with round function

Tags: iphone, nspredicate, rounding

I need to use NSPredicate with a round function.
e.g. :

```
Child* child1 = [self myFirstChild];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"round(SELF.age) > 12"];
BOOL twelveOrAlmostTwelve = [predicate evaluateWithObject:child1];
```

There is no such function in documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Predicates.pdf

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: There's no `round()` function, but there *are* `floor()` and `ceil()` functions.  The list of built-in functions is in the [`NSExpression` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-CJBDJCJE).

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own defined function in extensions class.
IE:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FUNCTION('12.12345','round:',3) = 12.123"]
```

and you need to define this method in your category for ie. NSString:

```
-(NSNumber*) round:(NSString*) precision;
```

look at the page:
http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate arbitrary predicate functions. In this case, however, the answer is trivial:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"SELF.age >= 11.5"];
```

Comment: Ok, real life dosen't get as simple as that, the example was too trivial. Maybe there is a way to use the existing functions (e.g ceiling, abs) to create round functionality?

Comment: Perhaps, but mostly you'd want to calculate the correct value to compare against, and plug it into the predicate as an argument. I'm having trouble picturing the case where rounding the input is better than computing the correct comparator. Unless you're also applying other functions like @median or the like. Keep in mind that predicates are very, very slow compared to just doing the math directly, unless you're doing large fetches with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have a quite complicated validation engine where the predicates are constructed from a definition coming from a web service. Those predicates are bound to e.g. text fields and evaluated when validation is required. This does get quite slow, but still acceptable regarding user experience. Arbitrary predicate functions would have been exactly what I need. If I figure out somehow how to do this, I'll post, thanks